# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'XYZ') - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, typeerror

hope everyone is having a good day so far.

I have a weird problem in a JavaScript. The Job of the Script is to order
the divs differently every time someone visits the page. For that i generate and array with random numbers, making sure that there are no doubled ones. Then i give every div its number and sort them before putting
them back onto the page. Right now, i get stuck at the part where i sort the divs in an array.

I get a TypeError that seems to make zero sense, since i already used "typeof" to see if the outputs are undefined, but they are solid numbers. 
Here is the Code:

HTML:

```
<div class="padding"></div>
<div class="MosaikBilder">1</div>
<div class="MosaikBilder">2</div>
<div class="MosaikBilder">3</div>
<div class="MosaikBilder">4</div>
<div class="MosaikBilder">5</div>
<div class="MosaikBilder">6</div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
<div class="padding"></div>
```

CSS:

```
title {
    display: none;
}

.padding {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.MosaikBilder {
    height: 50px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    color: white;
}
```

and now the Score, the JS:

```
var BilderListe = ["","", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "","","","","",""];
//generating an array until there are no doubled values
do{
    var funktionsfaehig = true;
    Zahlenzuweisung();
    Dopplungspruefung();
}while(funktionsfaehig == false);
console.log(BilderListe);
Zuordnung();

//generating a random list of numbers   
function Zahlenzuweisung(){
    for(var i=0 ; i<BilderListe.length; i++){
        BilderListe[i] = Math.round(Math.random()*1000);
        if(BilderListe[i] > 1000){
            BilderListe[i] = 1000;
        }
        //alert(BilderListe[i]);
    }
    console.log("Zahlenzuweisung " + BilderListe);
}

//sorting the list so it can be checked more easily, .sort did always miss one number for some reason
function Dopplungspruefung(){
    var Tauschen
    var PruefungsListe;

    PruefungsListe = BilderListe.slice();
    console.log("Dopplungspruefung ist " + BilderListe)
    console.log(PruefungsListe);
    do{
        var getauscht = false;
        for(i=0; i<PruefungsListe.length; i++){
            if(PruefungsListe[i] > PruefungsListe[i+1]){
                Tauschen = PruefungsListe[i];
                PruefungsListe[i] = PruefungsListe[i+1];
                PruefungsListe[i+1] = Tauschen;

                getauscht = true;
            }
        }           
    }while(getauscht == true);
    console.log(PruefungsListe);
    console.log("Nach der Prüfung ist " + BilderListe);
    DerPruefer(PruefungsListe);
}

//checking the sorted list for doubled numbers
//if there are any, new numbers will be generated
function DerPruefer(PruefungsListe){    
    console.log("Der Pruefer wurde gestartet");
    for(i=0; i < PruefungsListe.length; i++){
        if(PruefungsListe[i] == PruefungsListe[i+1]){
            console.log("Etwas war gleich");
            funktionsfaehig = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

//all divs needed get gathered in one array
//then every element gets a random generated value
function Zuordnung(){
    var AlleBilder = document.getElementsByClassName("MosaikBilder");
    for(i=0; i<AlleBilder.length; i++){
        AlleBilder[i].value = BilderListe[i]
    }
    var Check = AlleBilder[0].value;
    console.log(Check);
    //Bubblesort the Pictures
    BilderSortierer(AlleBilder);
}

//Now i want to sort the elements by their value
//But they TypeError occurs, claiming that the 2nd one
//Has the value 'undefined (log says its a number)
function BilderSortierer(AlleBilder){
    var i = 0
    console.log(AlleBilder[i]);
    console.log(AlleBilder[i].value);
    console.log(typeof(AlleBilder[i].value));
    console.log(AlleBilder[i+1]);
    console.log(AlleBilder[i+1].value);
    console.log(typeof(AlleBilder[i+1].value));
    var Wechsler
    var BilderCheck = true;
    do{
        for(i=0; i<AlleBilder.length; i++){
            if(AlleBilder[i].value > AlleBilder[i+1].value){
                Wechsler = AlleBilder[i];
                AlleBilder[i] = AlleBilder[i+1];
                AlleBilder[i+1] = Wechsler;
                BilderCheck = false;
            }
        }       
    }while(BilderCheck == true);
}
```

this is the console log, so you don't need to try it yourself:

```
[Log] Zahlenzuweisung       142,595,442,790,668,978,652,721,154,280,819,239,425,65,270  (Bilderordner.html, line 64)
[Log] Dopplungspruefung ist 142,595,442,790,668,978,652,721,154,280,819,239,425,65,270 (Bilderordner.html, line 72)
[Log] Array (15) (Bilderordner.html, line 73)
[Log] Array (15) (Bilderordner.html, line 86)
[Log] Nach der PrÃ¼fung ist 142,595,442,790,668,978,652,721,154,280,819,239,425,65,270 (Bilderordner.html, line 87)
[Log] Der Pruefer wurde gestartet (Bilderordner.html, line 92)
[Log] Array (15) (Bilderordner.html, line 53)
[Log] 142 (Bilderordner.html, line 108)
[Log] <div class="MosaikBilder">1</div> (Bilderordner.html, line 115)

[Log] 142 (Bilderordner.html, line 116)
[Log] number (Bilderordner.html, line 117)
[Log] <div class="MosaikBilder">2</div> (Bilderordner.html, line 118)

[Log] 595 (Bilderordner.html, line 119)
[Log] number (Bilderordner.html, line 120)
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'AlleBilder[i+1].value')
```

Maybe someone has an idea why it occurs and how to fix it. I Didn't change any of the names or logs in case they are part of the problem. But like i said earlier, both values are typeof numbers, so why does the 2nd one not work in the if-loop?

Also, if there is any other way to do it more easily, feel free to correct me, i am relatively new and thankful for any help.

Best regards and thanks a lot in advance

Comment: When `i` is `AlleBilder.length - 1` then `AlleBilder[i+1]` will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple

`AlleBilder[i+1]` is undefined when you are at the last index.

So you would need to change your loop

```
for(i=0; i<AlleBilder.length-1; i++){
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your final iteration will look for an element in your array that doesn't exist (i.e. out of bounds)

Try changing

```
for(i=0; i<AlleBilder.length; i++)
```

to

```
for(i=0; i<AlleBilder.length-1; i++)
```

Comment: thanks a lot @TLP! This really helped :) But why do the functions before this one work without the -1?

Comment: Because the other don't look for `PruefungsListe[i+1]`. Remember that the last element in an array is `length-1`: an array with a length of 10 has elements 0-9, so element 10 doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok i think i understood that a little bit, but why isn't the [i+1] element in the for-loops of the functions Dopplungpruefung und DerPruefer behaving like this?

Comment: That's because of a JavaScript quirk where it only returns an error if you try to access a member of an object that doesn't exist in the array where you are looking for it. It doesn't return an error if you try to access the root of such an object (i.e. without a dot). To illustrate, try to run this code: `let a=[1,2,3]; console.log(a[2] > a[3]);`. This will not return an error, but the following will: `let b = [{n:1},{n:2},{n:3}]; console(b[2].n > b[3].n);`

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, this was perfectly explained! Great example (y)